# Using DeserializeAsAttribute on a key that has a "." in it

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm unabled to get a value for a key that has a `.` in it when using RestSharp's [DeserializeAsAttribute](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/RestSharp/RestSharp/DeserializeAsAttribute).

Here's my JSON:

```
{
    ".issued": "Wed, 24 Jun 2015 20:59:57 GMT",
    ".expires": "Wed, 08 Jul 2015 20:59:57 GMT"
}
```

Model I'm deserializing:

```
class TokenModel
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = ".issued")]
    public DateTime Issued { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = ".expires")]
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}
```

Debugging:

```
GetToken() - success - issued: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
GetToken() - success - expires: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

I also have the `RestRequest.DateFormat` set to:

```
request.DateFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'";
```

I've followed the https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization docs as best I can without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to figure this out.  I had to parse the response content manually...

```
    Regex IssuedRegex = new Regex(@"\""\.issued\"":\s*\""([^\""]+)\""");
    Regex ExpiresRegex = new Regex(@"\""\.expires\"":\s*\""([^\""]+)\""");

    var response = authClient.Execute<AccessToken>(request);
    AccessToken = response.Data;

    // workaround for bug in RestSharp
    var im = IssuedRegex.Match(response.Content);
    if (im.Success)
        AccessToken.Issued = DateTime.ParseExact(im.Groups[1].Value, "R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var em = ExpiresRegex.Match(response.Content);
    if (em.Success)
        AccessToken.Expires = DateTime.ParseExact(em.Groups[1].Value, "R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```